# Remove children from object graph (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How can I recurse child arrays in a given object graph and remove items without knowing the array name?  All of my objects have three audit fields:

```
{
  id,            // String
  userId,        // String
  createdDate,   // Date
  updatedDate,   // Date - OPTIONAL
  deletedDate    // Date - OPTIONAL
}
```

If the `deletedDate` property exists then the item should be removed from the array.

Example:

```
var companies = [
    {
      id : 'abc123',
      name : 'ABC, Inc.',
      employees: [
        {
          id : 'abc-01',
          name : 'Joe',
          createdDate: '1/1/2015',
          userId : 'asdf87612'
        },
        {
          id : 'abc-02',
          name : 'Mike',
          createdDate: '1/1/2015',
          deletedDate: '1/2/2015'
          userId : 'asdf87612'
        }
      ]
      createdDate: '1/1/2015',
      userId : 'asdf87612'
    }
];
```

The function needs to be generic enough to 1) find all properties that are arrays, and 2) recurse the array to find items that have the `deletedDate` property set, and 3) remove the item from the array if the `deletedDate` value has been set.

In the example above, the Employee "Mike" would be removed from the array.

I've been trying to use Lodash for this but have not been successful... and just deleted my test file while I was experimenting.  I'll recreate it again so the folks on SO know I'm not trying to slack off.

**Original Method**
This was my first (rather ugly) attempt at it:

```
function removeDeleted (itemOrArray) {
    if (itemOrArray == null || typeof itemOrArray == 'undefined') { return itemOrArray; }
    var result = [],
        items = (itemOrArray instanceof Array) ? itemOrArray : [itemOrArray];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        if (items[i].dateDeleted) { continue; }
        for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(items[i]).length; k += 1) {
            var key = Object.keys(items[i])[k];
            if (items[i][key] instanceof Array) {
                items[i][key] = removeDeleted(items[i].key);
            }
        }
        result.push(items[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with lodash should work.

```
var companies = companies.map(function(company) {
  // map each value of the company
  return _.omitBy(_.mapValues(company, function(value) {
    // if the value is an array, remove an object in the array if the `deletedDate` prop exists
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
      return _.remove(value, function(o) { return 'deletedDate' in o });
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }), function(value) {
    return Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0;
  });
});
```

Docs:

1. [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)
2. [remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) (like filter)
3. [omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs#omitBy)

Comment: Is there any way to remove the child array completely if all of the items were removed?  That's where I've gotten stuck.

Comment: @G.Deward, yup, edited my answer with the solution (use omitBy as well)

Comment: Man, you're awesome.  I can't tell you how long I've spent on this.

Comment: @G.Deward, glad it was useful. I've spent many times banging my head against the wall on these sorts of problems. What helps me is if you look at it in a sequence of steps... e.g., first do this, once you're in that state, do the next thing, etc. Related to "functional programming". Avoiding direct state mutations, and instead just passing state through a series of transformations. Easier to reason about, I think.